# Coordinate transformation of projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This is an exercise from  Introduction to Plane Algebraic Curves by Kunz:

> Let $c:\mathbb{P}^2(K) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2(K)$ be the coordinate transformation that sends points
> $[1:0:0],[0:1:0],[-1:0:1],[0,1,1]$
>
> to points
>
> $[1:0:0],[0:1:0],[0:0:1],[1,1,1]$.
>
> a)Determine the equation of the curve
> $$X_0^2X_2-X_0X_1^2+X_0X_2^2-2X_0X_1X_2-X_1^2X_2-2X_1X_2^2$$
> in the new coordinate system.
>
> b) Is this curve irreducible?

So I think in order to do b) I need to use the form of curve from a). But I am not sure how to do this, the question gives the transformation of 4 points, but I think we only need 3 of them. Also after I get the transformation matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How should I apply this to the curve?

Comment: For a general projective transformation you need four point pairs. As it happens, this one fixes lines of the form $(0,a,b)$, so if you designate such a line as the line at infinity, then the transformation is affine and only needs three point pairs to specify it. On the other hand, choosing a line that is its own image is in itself an additional constraint, so that doesn’t really reduce their number.

Comment: Hint: let $Y_i$ denote the new coordinates. Then $Y_0=X_0+X_2$, $Y_1=X_1$, and $Y_2=X_2$, so $X_0=Y_0-Y_2$, and we can substitute in to the equation. What happens next?